# Creating line from 2 points in Google Earth Engine Python API

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

I try to create a lineString object from 2 points in using the Earthengine Python API:

```py
point0 = ee.Geometry.Point([0,0])
point1 = ee.Geometry.Point([0,1])
line = ee.Geometry.LineString([point1, point0], geodesic=True)
line.getInfo()
```

But I get the following error:

```
EEException: Projection: Argument 'crs': Invalid type.
Expected type: String.
Actual type: Boolean.
Actual value: true
```

This is weird because LineString has no crs arguments.

Is it a bug or am I making a mistake ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the Python API doesn't actually provide a valid default `proj` value. The [docs](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-geometry-linestring) probaby could use an update to clarify. This works:

```
point0 = ee.Geometry.Point([0,0])
point1 = ee.Geometry.Point([0,1])
line = ee.Geometry.LineString([point1, point0], proj='EPSG:4326', geodesic=True)
```